# Babel - Romanian ' or \c

Tags: babel, characters

I want to use some shortcuts to produce special character in Romanian. One of them is to use the command `\c` but also I know that is possible to use the following character:  `'` .

example **`\c si`** or **`'si`** produce same word.

How can I use **`'`**  ?

It is written that I used an old interface to call `babel`.

Comment: Are you asking how you can do to type the character `'` which is not available in your keyboard?

Comment: no. that character is like a command. like in example: \c si or 'si is same word.

Comment: I know because I saw last year a latex document where it was used in whole document '. I don't know how to use it. I usually use \c, \^, \u, but now I want to know how to use ' to produce same word. EXAMPLE: 'si=\c si.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Try this : http://blypt.blogspot.ro/2011/07/romanian-diacritics-in-latex.html It worked for me...

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 11):

The `babel` style for Romanian provides no shorthands, but you can define them easily:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage{combelow}

\useshorthands{'}
\defineshorthand{'s}{\cb{s}}
\defineshorthand{'t}{\cb{t}}
\defineshorthand{'S}{\cb{S}}
\defineshorthand{'T}{\cb{T}}

\begin{document}

Bucure'sti 't 'T 'S

\end{document}
```

EDIT. Added some letters and use comma below with `combelow`.

Comment: I have one question. I saw that with {'} it can be produced all the special letters in Romanian.  what you said me, produce only one. can you help me?

Comment: Actually the shortcut should provide the "comma under" accent, not the cedilla.

Comment: @luli I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to using shorthands is going with UTF-8 input encoding.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage{combelow}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{Ș}{\cb{S}}
\newunicodechar{ș}{\cb{s}}
\newunicodechar{Ț}{\cb{T}}
\newunicodechar{ț}{\cb{t}}

\begin{document}

București ȘșȚț

\end{document}
```

[image]

In any case I'm afraid that hyphenation will not go past these special letters (but it would be the same with shorthands), because the required glyphs must be constructed from different pieces.

With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you can ensure correct input and hyphenation;  Romanian fonts are available with (pdf)LaTeX, but their usage is not really well supported. Here's a way to use the real glyphs and not composed ones.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[QX,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\addto\extrasromanian{\fontencoding{QX}\selectfont}
\addto\noextrasromanian{\fontencoding{\encodingdefault}\selectfont}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{Ș}{\c S} % qxenc provides the precomposed combination
\newunicodechar{ș}{\c s} % ditto
\newunicodechar{Ț}{\c T} % ditto
\newunicodechar{ț}{\c t} % ditto

\begin{document}

București ȘșȚț

\end{document}
```

The Latin Modern fonts, as well as the TeX Gyre ones, support the QX encoding
(thanks to [Robert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7674/robert) for the information).

With a QX encoded font, one can also use the shorthand version, in case UTF-8 encoding is difficult to use.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[QX,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\addto\extrasromanian{\fontencoding{QX}\selectfont}
\addto\noextrasromanian{\fontencoding{\encodingdefault}\selectfont}

\useshorthands{'}
\defineshorthand{'S}{\c S}
\defineshorthand{'s}{\c s}
\defineshorthand{'T}{\c T}
\defineshorthand{'t}{\c t}

\begin{document}

Bucure'sti 'S's'T't

\end{document}
```

However, QX encoded fonts are not the ultimate answer, because they don't contain the `Ă` and `ă` glyphs, which are essential for Romanian. They contain `Â`, `â`, `Î` and `î`, though.

Comment: _"Romanian fonts are unfortunately unavailable with (pdf)LaTeX"_: this is not the whole truth. At least Latin Modern as well as the TeX Gyre fonts contain the real "textcommabelow" glyphs in QX encoding, they only require additional code to be made accessible. See [this post](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2008-August/017204.html), which thoroughly summarises the Romanian TeX situation, but unfortunately doesn't seem to have led to any progress in this area (`qxenc.def` is still the same).

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the information; I'll try and investigate.